# Bootstrap List Group with oversized font-awesome icons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have a Bootstrap 5 List Group object on the page. I'd like to add oversize Font Awesome icons to make it a little more visually interesting.

I have successfully added the icon using a span and some styling but am having an issue with the icon falling out of the bounds of the list-group-item. See the images below.

[image]

[image]

I'd like to keep the icon within the list-group-item but can't seem to make it work. I have tried z-indexing it but that doesn't work.

I think it might be related to where the span is perhaps?

```css
.pages-icon {
  font-size: 90px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: -20px;
  transform: rotate(11.81deg);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div class="list-group rounded-10">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action w-100">
    <span class="pages-icon"><i class="fa-thin fa-people-group text-cpPink"></i></span> Our People
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
    <span class="pages-icon"><i class="fa-thin fa-building text-cpBlue"></i></span> Offices
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Departments</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Business Information</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Events & What's On</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Events & What's On</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like limiting overflow with Bootstrap's [utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/overflow/), along with a more robust negative top position, does the trick. Note that you don't really need the wrapping span elements.

I added an opacity effect for fun.

```css
.pages-icon {
  font-size: 90px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: -50%;
  transform: rotate(11.81deg);
  opacity: 0.75;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.list-group-item:hover .pages-icon {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<div class="list-group rounded-10">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action overflow-hidden w-100">
    <i class="pages-icon fa-solid fa-people-group text-danger"></i> Our People
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action overflow-hidden">
    <i class="pages-icon fa-solid fa-building text-info"></i> Offices
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action overflow-hidden">Departments</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action overflow-hidden">Business Information</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action overflow-hidden">Events & What's On</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action overflow-hidden">Events & What's On</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `overflow: hidden` to your list-items. This will hide anything that overflows outside of the container.  This can be done with a bootstrap class as well.

Comment: My answer may well end up _below_ yours. You should either link to specific answers, reference a user by name, or just omit that part.